# Coloring one linetype in geom_line (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the below link to a line plot, I'm showing the progression of a stat over 10 games with different linetypes indicating year. Is there a way to add a color just to the 2016 line so it stands out? I tried using scale_manual_color with a vector of different color values but that didn't work. Below is also the code I'm using. I appreciate any help.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = games1, y = diff_cum, group = Year, linetype = Year)) + 
    geom_line(size = 1) + 
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to add a `color` (or `colour`) aesthetic

```
ggplot(df, 
  aes(
     x = games1, 
     y = diff_cum, 
     group = Year, 
     color = Year, # This right here!
     linetype = Year)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("my","colours","for","year"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ifelse` to set aes groups on the fly

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = hp, group = cyl)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = ifelse(cyl == 6, "6", "not6"))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black"))
```